# Opening next Activity

Tags: java, android

I have have a problem here with my code. I want to open the next Activity using submit button but I'm having issues. Can anybody help me on the mistake I am making so that I can implement it? Thanks

```
    public class Chairperson extends Activity implements        View.OnClickListener{
    TextView textView;
    Button submit_btn;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chairperson);
    submit_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit_btn);
    submit_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome_txt);
    String message = getIntent().getStringExtra("message");
    textView.setText(message);
    Button submit_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit_btn);
    final TextView submitTextView = (TextView)  findViewById(R.id.submitTextView);

    final RadioGroup rg1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg1);

    submit_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Get the checked Radio Button ID from Radio Grou[
            int selectedRadioButtonID = rg1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

            // If nothing is selected from Radio Group, then it return -1
            if
                    (selectedRadioButtonID != -1) {
                RadioButton selectedRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedRadioButtonID);
                String selectedRadioButtonText = selectedRadioButton.getText().toString();
                submitTextView.setText(selectedRadioButtonText + "  selected.");

            } else {
                submitTextView.setText("Nothing selected .");
            }
          }

        });


    }

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
       startActivity(new Intent(this, ViceChairperson.class));
        }
      }
```

Comment: who is the second `onClick` referred to?

Comment: `I'm having issues`???

Comment: @magicleon,second onClick was for  opening next activity

Comment: yes, but it's not bound to anything. I understood that you want to start the activity when pressing `submit_btn` right? You cannot have two different `onClick` methods for the same button. You tap the `submit_btn`, check for the radio button and launch the next activity from there, no need for anything else. The second `onClick` will never be invoked, since the button is bound to the other.

Comment: i now get the logic part of it...so i should introduce another button or?

Comment: Nah, you should just use one `onClick` method. You should have used two buttons if there were two different things to do, but this is not the case, since you just want to check the `RadioButton` and launch the activity accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a code for your button, delete all previous code for submit_btn in your code and replace with this

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
addListenerOnButton();

public void addListenerOnButton() {
final Context context = this;
submit_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit_btn);

submit_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
       if (radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1)
 {
 Toast.makeText(context, "Select an option.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
 else{
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ViceChairperson.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

        }
 }
 });

}
}
```

If you have any issues please let me know.

Comment: thanks for reply and code too,but in my case i wanted submit button to confirm if radio button is checked and if yes it opens next activity also if no selected radio button hence it does not open next activity. that's my challenge.can you help further

Comment: sorry for that..i am saying the code you gave makes radio button open next activity even if no radio button is checked

Comment: okay i understand, just a moment to revise my code, what was wrong with your own code by the way?

Comment: my code was working fine the only problem was going to next activity with submit button  after checking radio button

Comment: working on it just a moment i will let you know the progress

Comment: on this line of your code if (radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1) it gives this error   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.RadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()' on a null object reference

Comment: you are meant to instantiate your radio group for example `final RadioGroup rg1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg1);`  and the likes , my code just shows you how to compare what you need to be done

Comment: thank you very much friend @ Kennedy. am happy for your humble time  assist me,it worked at long last.thanks again

Comment: sorry Kennedy it seems i have not reached reputation (You must have 20 reputation)

Comment: its alright, you can mark the answer as right if it helped you out

Comment: it did a lot...hopes you wont mind helping next time

Answer (score 0):

Just move the line

```
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViceChairperson.class));
```

after the `if (selectedRadioButtonID != -1)` check. 
If that check succeeds you start the new activity, if not, nothing is launched.
There's no need for the second `onClick` method, which is not bound to anything and will never be invoked.

Comment: i have tried but it says..Cannot resolve constructor 'Intent(anonymous android.view.View.OnClickListener.java.lang.Class

Comment: sorry my mistake. Try with `getApplicationContext()` instead, this should work (I checked and used this on one of my apps). I edited my code